# Change compiler command line with Bazel

Tags: c++, bazel

I'd like to have complete control over the command line arguments Bazel passes to the compiler when compiling and linking C++ files. **For example**, I'd like to use a G++ from a custom path, I'd like to change `-std=c++0x` to `-std=c++14` and remove `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` - with the following constraints:

- Avoid setting the compiler via `CC` envvar, as it is fragile
- Avoid using `--crosstool_top` et. al, as I understand Bazel is moving away from it
- Be compatible with --all_incompatible_changes
- Do not simply override those args via `copts`, as it is fragile and makes error prone commands

Preferably, I'd like to get the auto detected, generated toolchain, modify it, and commit it to my workspace, to be used by every C++ target in the workspace, including imported, from source compiled workspaces.

I looked at [Toolchains](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/toolchains.html), [Configuring C++ toolchain](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/tutorial/cc-toolchain-config.html), [rules_cc](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_cc) - but I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

The default arguments (e.g: `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` or `-std=c++0x`) can be removed by disabling the [`default_compile_flags`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/tools/cpp/cc_toolchain_config.bzl#L527) feature that provides them:

```
$ bazel build ... --features=-default_compile_flags
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a `.bazelrc` to your project. Add the lines

```
build:your_config --cxxopt=-std=c++14
```

Build your code:

```
bazel build --config=your_config //...
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach does not directly allow the configuration of the compiler binary and removal of arguments (e.g: `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this in your BUILD file for the entire package:

```
package(features = ["-default_compile_flags"])
```

or on a specific binary:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "cppversion",
    srcs = ["cppversion.cpp"],
    copts = ["--std=c++14"],
    features = ["-default_compile_flags"]
)
```